# IBOutlet are nil in Objective C before the view controller is presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, iboutlet, presentation

```
UIStoryboard *gamePlaySB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_GAME_PLAY bundle:nil];
CustomAlertViewController *customAlertVC = [gamePlaySB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:CUSTOM_ALERT_VIEW_CONTROLLER];
```

I have initialised the `viewcontroller` as shown above but when trying to access the `IBOutlet` label from the initialised `viewcontroller` and set its text, the label is nil.

So, I have to pass the value to a variable and then use that in the `viewDidLoad` to set the title. Is there any other easy way of doing this?

Comment: You should indeed pass through an additional variable. Also, if there are multiple properties you need to set, I'd suggest to use "mini" Model class: `CustomAlertModel` for instance that have all the properties needed to update the views in the ViewController. For single properties, like an Label, just had a NSString for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CustomAlertViewController *customAlertVC = [gamePlaySB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:CUSTOM_ALERT_VIEW_CONTROLLER];
__unused UIView* view = customAlertVC.view; // this will load everything and call viewDidLoad
customAlertVC.property.text = @"blahblah";
```

This is if really want to set it from outside. But as per @D. Mika answer, this is not advisable.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a ViewController is to manage the elements of a view. The "user" of a ViewController should not know the structure of the View and therefore the outlets used. Therefore, I wouldn't consider it useful for you to want to access the outlets outside the ViewController.
The way to provide the data to be displayed via properties of the ViewController is common and also useful.

For the sake of completeness, it should be mentioned that you can force the view of a view controller to be loaded by accessing the view property. But, as I said, this is not a proper technique. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I have initialised the view controller as shown above but when trying
>   to access the IBOutlet label from the initialised view controller and
>   set its text, the label is nil.

That's because the view (`UILabel`) is not initialised yet before you're presenting/pushing the controller.

> So, I have to pass the value to a variable and then use that in the
>   viewDidLoad to set the title. Is there any other easy way of doing
>   this?

Yes. And yes. If you're declaring the view (`UILabel`) **lazily**, you can directly pass the value there, like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let vc2 = VC2()
        vc2.label.text = "HELLO"
        self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class VC2: UIViewController {

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
        label.textColor = .gray
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .red

        self.view.addSubview(self.label)
        self.label.center.equalTo(self.view.center)
    }
}
```